# How to properly indent class variables containing classes with pprint

Tags: python

I have a custom class that contains objects of another class, structured something like this (init is pre-populated for demonstration):

```
class Outer:

    def __init__(self, inner_class_holder=None):
        self.outer_list = [["example_list"], list(range(5))]
        self.outer_dict = dict(zip(list("abcdefghij"), range(10)))
        self.inner_class_holder = inner_class_holder

    def __repr__(self):
        import pprint
        return "Class " + str(self.__class__.__name__) + ":\n" + pprint.pformat(vars(self))


class Inner:

    def __init__(self):
        self.inner_list = list("demo")
        self.inner_dict = dict(zip(list("nope"), range(4)))

    def __repr__(self):
        import pprint
        return "Class " + str(self.__class__.__name__) + ":\n" + pprint.pformat(vars(self))
```

Both contain other variables like lists and dicts that I've been able to print well with pprint.pformat() and __repr__ individually, so running the following produces the results I'd expect:

```
>>> print(Outer())

Class Outer:
{'inner_class_holder': None,
 'outer_dict': {'a': 0,
                'b': 1,
                'c': 2,
                'd': 3,
                'e': 4,
                'f': 5,
                'g': 6,
                'h': 7,
                'i': 8,
                'j': 9},
 'outer_list': [['example_list'], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]]}

>>> print(Inner())

Class Inner:
{'inner_dict': {'e': 3, 'n': 0, 'o': 1, 'p': 2},
 'inner_list': ['d', 'e', 'm', 'o']}
```

However, when I try to pretty-print the outer class when it has instances of the inner class, this happens:

```
>>> outer = Outer([Inner(), Inner()])
>>> print(outer)

Class Outer:
{'inner_class_holder': [Class Inner:
{'inner_dict': {'e': 3, 'n': 0, 'o': 1, 'p': 2},
 'inner_list': ['d', 'e', 'm', 'o']},
                        Class Inner:
{'inner_dict': {'e': 3, 'n': 0, 'o': 1, 'p': 2},
 'inner_list': ['d', 'e', 'm', 'o']}],
 'outer_dict': {'a': 0,
                'b': 1,
                'c': 2,
                'd': 3,
                'e': 4,
                'f': 5,
                'g': 6,
                'h': 7,
                'i': 8,
                'j': 9},
 'outer_list': [['example_list'], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]]}
```

While the "Class Inner" lines are properly indented by pprint, none of their bodies are, which makes the pprint much less helpful. Is there a way to get pprint to indent the inner objects correctly, particularly without specifically handling each variable in the class?

Comment: The problem is that since you're calling `pformat` yourself through `__repr__`, pprint effectively has no way to know the different levels of indentation (i.e. the inner `pformat` can't know that it should indent the output to a specific level as it would when pprint itself does the recursion).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was, rather than try to feed pprint the indent it would need for each inner block, instead convert the object itself to primitive components that pprint handles natively, as follows:

```py
def get_object_as_primitive(obj):
    if issubclass(type(obj), Printable):
        return obj.get_vars_dict_as_primitives()
    else:
        return obj

def get_dict_as_primitives(input_dict):
    output_dict = {}
    for key, value in input_dict.items():
        typ = type(value)
        # lists and tuples must be iterated through to convert their inner contents
        if issubclass(typ, (list, tuple)):
            value_to_add = [get_object_as_primitive(item) for item in value]
            if issubclass(typ, tuple):
                value_to_add = tuple(value_to_add)
        # dicts can be handled recursively
        elif issubclass(typ, dict):
            value_to_add = get_dict_as_primitives(value)
        else:
            value_to_add = get_object_as_primitive(value)
        output_dict[key] = value_to_add
    return output_dict

import pprint

class Printable:

    def get_vars_dict_as_primitives(self):
        vars_dict = {'__class__': str(self.__class__)}
        vars_dict.update(vars(self))
        return get_dict_as_primitives(vars_dict)

    def __str__(self):
        return pprint.pformat(self.get_vars_dict_as_primitives())
```

Using this, any class that is a subclass of Printable will use pprint correctly with default settings, or a class that wants different settings can use its get_vars_dict_as_primitives() to retrieve the dictionary and format accordingly.

Rerunning the example from the question (after making Outer and Inner subclasses of Printable) provides the following result:

```py
>>> outer = Outer([Inner(), Inner()])
>>> print(outer)

{'__class__': "<class '__main__.Outer'>",
 'inner_class_holder': [{'__class__': "<class '__main__.Inner'>",
                         'inner_dict': {'e': 3, 'n': 0, 'o': 1, 'p': 2},
                         'inner_list': ['d', 'e', 'm', 'o']},
                        {'__class__': "<class '__main__.Inner'>",
                         'inner_dict': {'e': 3, 'n': 0, 'o': 1, 'p': 2},
                         'inner_list': ['d', 'e', 'm', 'o']}],
 'outer_dict': {'a': 0,
                'b': 1,
                'c': 2,
                'd': 3,
                'e': 4,
                'f': 5,
                'g': 6,
                'h': 7,
                'i': 8,
                'j': 9},
 'outer_list': [['inner_list'], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]]}
```

This is not a perfect solution, as keys of dictionaries are not converted, but if a custom class is being used as a dict key, it's likely that a custom __repr__ is necessary anyway.